# Getting previous day datetime from arrow

Tags: python, datetime, arrow-python

I can get current datetime from arrow like this:

```
arrow.utcnow().date()
```

or

```
arrow.get('2017-02-01').date()
```

How can I get the previous day datetime? This does not work:

```
arrow.utcnow().date() - 1
```

or

```
 arrow.get('2017-02-01').date() - 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thanks kayluhb. update is to use shift:

```
arrow.utcnow().shift(days=-1)
```

you can use replace:

```
 arrow.utcnow().replace(days=-1)
```

Comment: Using plural values with replace is being deprecated in favor of 'shift' https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#replace-shift.  This should become arrow.utcnow().shift(days=-1)